# unknown spice device type [LT spice]

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice

[image]

i am working with tlp292-4 which is 4 array optical isolator ,i am trying to do the simulation of the component ,i have downloaded the simulation model from the manufacturers website but i am getting a unknown spice device type error .how should i resolve this arror?

site from which is downloaded the spice model:https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/optoelectronics/detail.TLP292.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an encrypted model for PSPICE. You'll need to  use the LTspice encrypted model, which Toshiba also has available.

Also you'll need to assign R5 a value before the simulation will work, but that's not your problem here.

Comment: @ SpehroPefhany thanks for help